# Error when building vue application in docker build

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, npm, vite

I get a build error when running npm run build in my dockerfile, everything works perfectly when I run npm run build localy but in the docker build command it returns an error

The error in the docker build command

```
------
 > [6/6] RUN npm run build:
#11 0.587
#11 0.587 > resto@0.0.0 build
#11 0.587 > vite build
#11 0.587
#11 1.706 vite v3.0.9 building for production...
#11 1.777 transforming...
#11 3.161 ✓ 289 modules transformed.
#11 3.161 [vite:load-fallback] Could not load /src/Views/Forget.vue (imported by src/router/index.js): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/src/Views/Forget.vue'
#11 3.161 error during build:
#11 3.161 Error: Could not load /src/Views/Forget.vue (imported by src/router/index.js): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/src/Views/Forget.vue'
------
```

Dockerfile

```
from node:16
ENV port=8080
copy package*.json ./
run npm install
run npm install -g http-server
copy . ./
run npm run build
cmd http-server -p $port dist/
```

my npm build script is just `vite build`

the import statement

```
import Forget from '@/Views/Forget.vue'
```

vite config

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite';
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite';
import { ElementPlusResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: '',
  plugins: [vue(),
    AutoImport({
      resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver()],
    }),
    Components({
      resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver()],
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```

Forget.vue is indeed located in ./src/views/Forget.vue

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer

Comment: I think this is because of path, you should remember, that in docker container you have different paths comparing to paths on your computer, and it's best practice to create work directories. So, before line with copy, try to put something like this: `WORKDIR /usr/src/app`

Comment: No that doesn't work, it just gives the same error but just with /usr/src/app prepended to the path of the file it cannot find. So instead of /src/views/forget.vue it says /usr/src/app/src/views/forget.vue